# Changing the Bounding box for UIImageview When Rotating

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview

I have an image that i rotate to face the touchLocation of the user, but because the bounding box of the UIImageView gets larger. This is ruining some collision detection.

My only plan is to code a new bounding box system to get each of the 4 points in a bounding box and rotate that myself, then write check collide code for that.

But before i do that, is there an easy way to do this?

My rotate code:

```
- (void)ObjectPointAtTouch{

     //Get the angle
     objectAngle = [self findAngleToPoint:Object :touchLocation];

     //Convert to radian, +90 for image alignment
     double radian =  (90 + objectAngle)/(180 / M_PI);

     //Transform by radian
     Object.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radian);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, as seen in other tutorials they also resize the scale off the bouncing box to fix this problem. CGAffineTransform scale I think it is.

Comment: Note that the `frame` property of a transformed `UIView` is undefined and should be ignored as per the documentation. In practice, it is the bounding rectangle, which won't do you a lot of good.